# add an onclick event to a div

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick

I don't know if this is allowed or even possible. Is it possible to create a div element with an onclick event so that if anywhere in the div's area is clicked, the event will run.

Eg
JAVASCRIPT:

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id="new-ID"; 
var onClickCommand = "printWorking()"   //printworking is another method that simply print "I'm working" to the console
divTag.onclick = onClickCommand;
console.log("onclick command added");
console.log(divTag.onclick);
parentDiv.appendChild(divTag); //This simply adds the div tag to the page.
```

HTML generated:

```
 <!--<div id="new-ID">-->

 whatever content I decide to add to the divTag.innerHTML
```

---

I notice how theres no onclick command going through to the generated div. Id this because its not allowed?

So 2 questions then.

1:Is it possible to add onclick to a div and have it occur if any area of the div is clicked.
2:If yes then why is the onclick method not going through to my div.

---

How very odd:

```
divTag.setAttribute("onclick", "printWorking()");
```

Above works flawlessly.

All below don't and wont pass the onclick to the div.

```
divTag.onclick=printWorking;

divTag.onclick="printWorking";

divTag.onclick="printWorking()";
```

Multiple other variants have been tried too.

Comment: IT would appear that setting onclick manually doesnt work as intended. I need to use .setAttriubte instead

Comment: @feeela. I did search. There are multiple examples which don't seem relevant or I've tried myself and have had no effect. The reason for which seems to be in relation to my above comment

Comment: If you had put the 'setAttribute' into an answer I would have upped it. So +1 for the question with answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is it possible to add onclick to a div and have it occur if any area of the div is clicked.

Yes … although it should be done with caution. Make sure there is some mechanism that allows keyboard access. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

> If yes then why is the onclick method not going through to my div.

You are assigning a string where a function is expected.

```
divTag.onclick = printWorking;
```

There are nicer ways to assign event handlers though, although older versions of Internet Explorer are sufficiently different that you should use a library to abstract it. There are plenty of [very small event libraries](http://microjs.com/#events) and every major library  [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)) has event handling functionality.

That said, now it is 2019, older versions of Internet Explorer no longer exist in practice so you can go direct to [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Are parentheses not required then?

Comment: If there were parentheses then it would be a function **call** and the return value would be assigned instead of the function itself.

Comment: That makes so much sense now. I've done that multiple times elsewhere in my code and had no idea what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Assign the onclick like this:

```
divTag.onclick = printWorking;
```

The onclick property will not take a string when assigned. Instead, it takes a function reference (in this case, `printWorking`).
The onclick attribute can be a string when assigned in HTML, e.g. `<div onclick="func()"></div>`, but this is generally not recommended.

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Everythings works well. You can't use divtag.onclick, becease "onclick" attribute doesn't exist. You need first create this attribute by using .setAttribute(). Look on this
http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute . You should read documentations first before you start giving "-".

Answer (score 0):

you can simply give a div an onclick function by just doing it as you'd do a button.

```
<div onclick="myfunction">Click me
</div>
<script>
function myfunction(){
alert("I gave a div an onClick!");
}
</script>
```