# How can I assign a function to an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want something like this:

```
div.onclick = function(x, y);
```

How can I do this without executing the function?

I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: just google `addEventListener` for it

Comment: Wrap the function call up in an anonymous function, or use `bind`

Comment: Is there nothing without using EventListeners?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909988/add-an-onclick-event-to-a-div

Answer (score 1):

Putting `()` after the function will call it. So don't do that.

```
div.onclick = function; // Note: function is a keyword and can't really be used as a variable name
```

That won't call the function with the arguments you want though. Event handler functions are always called with one argument: the event object.

You need to create a *new* function to call yours with those arguments.

```
function myhandler(event) {
    function(x, y); // Still not a valid name
}
div.onclick = myhandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var NewFunction = function(x){
// your function code
};
div.onclick = NewFunction;
```

Comment: I need those parameters in these brackets

Comment: When `NewFunction` is called, it will be passed one argument (the event object) but you've written it to expect two arguments. Function names starting with capital letters are traditionally reserved for constructor functions in JavaScript, and this isn't one.

Comment: @Progaros since "click" is a system generated event, the event details is automatically passed as the first parameter whenever it is triggered.

Comment: @Quentin correct. Edited accordingly. Maybe you can explain better to OPs comment. He probably wants to call something like, **add(a,b)**.on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunction = function(x,y){
  //Some code here
};
div.onclick = function(){ return myFunction(x, y); }
```

In the second function assignment you ofcourse should replace x and y with something known to that context.