# input selected item in dropdown list into multiple select list when button is clicked

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown list of the clients (`client`), a list that allows multiple selections (`clist`), and a button (`btn_add`) to add the client selected in `client` into the `clist`. The inputs in the `client` is taken from the database.

The problem is that when I click `btn_add`, nothing happens. What did I miss?

```
<select id="client" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;">
    <option value="">SELECT CLIENT</option>
     <?php $get='SELECT fname,lname FROM client ORDER BY fname';
        $result=mysql_query($get);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['fname'].' '.$row['lname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['fname'].' '.$row['lname']; ?></option>
    <?php }} ?>
</select>           

<div id="btn_add" style="float: right;" onclick="addonlist($('#client').val(), 3);" class="btn btn-default btn-medium" >ADD</div>
<br>
<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 355px;" id="clist" name="clist"></select>
```

Comment: Can you share "addonlist" js function?

Comment: Agreed please share that function. And, you are using a `div` with `onclick` - have a read of this (this may or may not help this situation but it is worth a read for code improvement) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909988/add-an-onclick-event-to-a-div

Comment: Ideally also use the browser console to check what happens when you click the `btn_add` div and report it here

Comment: why not use `<button>` instead of `<div>`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a `div` for a event scripted button. Heck, anything could be a button ;) Its all preference sometimes. But what IS effy, is the whole use of `onclick` in the first place when its apparent that jquery exists in their code.